# Is it possible to authenticate from SPA with Microsoft Authentication Library but without Redirect Uri?

Tags: javascript, oauth, single-page-application, azure-ad-msal

I'm creating a Javascript single page application. It requires a user to sign in during the implicit flow in order to use Microsoft Graph API later on.
I'm using MSAL.js and trying to adapt snippets from [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa) to get auth token from **authRedirectCallBack**

I realize that in other flows *redirect uri* (used after authentication) is essential to get the token and proceed with it.
However in my flow I have token processed in the Javascript callback function.

Is it possible to avoid providing *redirect uri* in App registration with Azure AD and/or during the code execution? I'd like not to bring the user to this redirect uri at all.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
var msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'my-app-id',
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
    forceRefresh: false
  }
};
const loginRequest = {scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'user.read']};
const msalClient = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
msalClient.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);
singIn();

async function singIn() {
  try {
    msalClient.loginPopup(loginRequest).then(function (response) {
      if (msalClient.getAccount()) {
        console.log('logged');
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function authRedirectCallBack(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    if (response.tokenType === "access_token") {
      console.log('token', response);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A redirect URI is required, as it is the main security mechanism we use to ensure the response is not returned to an unauthorized party, as the Implicit Flow relies on redirecting iframes/popups/windows back to your application with the response in the hash of the url.

Note, that if you use loginPopup/acquireTokenPopup/acquireTokenSilent, the end user will not really "see" this redirect page, as it is visited only briefly in either a hidden iframe (for acquireTokenSilent) or popup window. As soon as MSAL.js sees that the iframe/popup has been redirected back to your application, the response is parsed and the popup/iframe is closed.

We are working on a new version of the library that will switch to the Auth Code Flow w/ PKCE, which will not use hidden iframes, however, it will still use popups/redirects.

Can you further explain why you don't want your users to visit the redirect page?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The major issue with Redirect Uri for my case is that it needs to be static (as I need to save it with Azure AD). However, for me redirect uris would differ in some cases (e.g., new subdomains). This requires additional code complexity which I consider unnecessary for this already secure setup.

Comment: I see. I understand that the work associated with having to register numerous redirect URIs in the portal can be frustrating, but it is a necessary tradeoff to make sure only your application domain is able to receive tokens for your users.

Comment: I understand security concerns. However I disagree this should be mandatory. Having registered redirect url is a good safe option. Not more. It's obvious why this doesn't contribute much to security.
Redirection is controlled by browser, not by super auth server. Modern browsers offer official ways to fake redirection if needed. **chrome.identity.getRedirectURL** is just an example of how easy this *strict* redirect url requirement is detoured. But I guess potential attack would not rely on browser. HTTP(s) protocol is flexible enough to mimic any behaviour that server can not verify. IMHO.